# jquery .getJson where the request is json too

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I used to do my http request like this

```
GET /deals/couchbaseDocument/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "amenities" : "Maids "
        }
    }
}
```

on a specific tool

now i want to build a web app to call that request

this is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myForm").submit(function () {
        var query = '"query1":{"query1":{"match":{"amenities":"Maids"}}}';
        query = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(query));
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:9200/deals/couchbaseDocument/_search", query, function (results) {
            alert("success");
            alert(results);
        })
        .success(function () { alert(" second success"); })
        .error(function () {
            alert("error");
            alert(query);
        });
    });

})
```

my problem is : on chrome i keep getting the error alert, and on chrome i can't see the xhr request, even though i enabled every thing, while in firefox, there is no alert working at all

as you see, i am passing the parameter by hand

Comment: And it's the same port as the calling page

Comment: @adeneo the page is on port 10667

Comment: Same origin policy says that protocols, domains and **ports** must match.

Comment: @adeneo i can't use the port 9200 for my web page, because the port 9200 is the one that i am calling it to get the json data. did you get that please?

Comment: You may need to create a proxy that lives on the same port as the page which would then make a call to 9200 and return the data. On a side note, shouldn't it be `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse('{"query":{"match":{"amenities":"Maids"}}}'))` ?

Comment: @lshettyl i was having a problem with json.stringify and your code seems to solve it. but i still need a way to get the response. please. i am opening my page on the server by dupple click on the html file, so the url is : `file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/HttpRequests/index.html` is that wrong?

Comment: I thought you had a local server at 10667?

Comment: @lshettyl that is on my development machine (using visual studio) but the 9200 web service is on the server, so i copy my web page to the server and i open it there

Comment: plus please i can't see the xhr, i just can see them when the alert is working, and when i click "ok" in the alert they disappear, eventhough i made the save log for xhr in the chrome develoopment tools

Comment: First off all, you need a local server up and running to be able to achieve the first step to access the web service. `file:///C:...` isn't going to help.

Comment: @lshettyl okay i will deploy it on iis and come back to u

Comment: @lshettyl now i am getting the error alert, but in chrome developer tools,  can see the request, which is `http://68.168.100.142:9200/deals/couchbaseDocument/_search?{%22query%22:{%22match%22:{%22amenities%22:%22Maids%22}}}` and when i copy paste it to the browser, it gives me the results, when it is working on the browser, but not on my app?